# Divide a group into subgroups of size k

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, combinatorics

I am stuck with one problem :
Finding all the possible ways of **dividing a group of size 'n' into subgroups of size 'k'**. (here  **n%k =0**)

e.g., let set be {1,2,3,4,5,6} to divide into subgroups of 3 (k = 3,n = 6), possible sets are

a) {1,2,3},{4,5,6}

b) {1,3,5},{2,4,6}

c) {1,3,6},{2,4,5}

d) {1,3,4},{2,5,6} etc....

What i tried doing was, to first find all the combination of size k from the set.
Then loop through these combinations and find out which all combinations can be grouped together to find the list of subgroups.

But I believe the time complexity is pretty bad in this approach. Is there any better approach for this problem?

Comment: {1,2,3},{4,5,6} and {4,5,6},{1,2,3} - Do you consider as the same dividing or not?

Comment: Please show us your code.  Your description doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a recursive method. I think this one has the optimal running time, since it exactly produces all needed subsets.

```
public static void solve(int[] a, int k, int i, List<List<Integer>> subsets) {
    if (i == a.length) {
        for (List<Integer> subset : subsets) {
            System.out.print(subset);               
        }
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        // loop over all subsets and try to put a[i] in
        for (int j = 0; j < subsets.size(); j++) {                 
            if (subsets.get(j).size() < k) {
                // subset j not full
                subsets.get(j).add(a[i]);
                solve(a, k, i+1, subsets); // do recursion
                subsets.get(j).remove((Integer)a[i]);

                if (subsets.get(j).size() == 0) {
                     // don't skip empty subsets, so you won't get duplicates
                     break;
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int k = 3;

    List<List<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(a.length / k);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length / k; i++)
        subsets.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(k));
    solve(a, k, 0, subsets);
}
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3][4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 4][3, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 5][3, 4, 6]
[1, 2, 6][3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 4][2, 5, 6]
[1, 3, 5][2, 4, 6]
[1, 3, 6][2, 4, 5]
[1, 4, 5][2, 3, 6]
[1, 4, 6][2, 3, 5]
[1, 5, 6][2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: You can specify the capacity of the `ArrayList`s you use in their constructors so there won't be expensive expansions.

Comment: @G.Bach smart! I'll add that

Answer (score 1):

Think about it combinatorially. If `n % k != 0`, you can't do it because you'll end up with one set that has less than `k` elements, so start off with checking whether that is the case.

Afterwards, all you need to do is recursively produce k-combinations from an `n-i*k` set for all `i in [0; n/k]`. Algorithms for producing all k-combinations of a given set can be found on SO easy enough. The idea is: there are (n choose k) possible such sets you can choose for your first set; from the remaining `n-k` elements, you can choose ((n-k) choose k) sets); from the remaining `n-2k` elements, you can choose ((n-2k) choose k) sets and so on. Assuming the order of your sets doesn't matter, you have `(n choose k) * ((n-k) choose k) * ... * ((n-(n-1)k) choose k) / ((n/k)!)` possibilities to choose your sets, which depending on k can be exponential in the number of elements your original set has, so if you really want to produce each and every one of them, you won't get below exponential complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I found a formula for the # of possible subgroupings, in case anyone finds it interesting. (Would this be considered too off-topic? Am I posting this correctly?)
First let `m = n/k` be the # of subgroups. Now let the first subgroup be fixed as the first k elements of the group, the second subgroup be the next k, and so on. If we consider all possible permutations of the group, this will give us all the different subgroupings. There are `n!` permutations of the n elements, but we don't care about ordering, so we factor out the `k!` permutations of each of the m subgroups and the `m!` permutations of the subgroups themselves. This gives us:
`n!/(m!*(k!)^m)`.
As a check, if k = 1 or k = n, this gives us 1 subgrouping. In the original example, n = 6, k = 3, m = 2, and we get 10 possible subgroupings (which Heuster's code found).
Now, if you compare this expression to the one G. Bach gave and use `(n choose k) = n!/(k!*(n-k)!)`, you will see that all the `(n-k)!` terms cancel and it reduces to the expression above.
Bonus: if you use Stirling's approximation for `n!`, then the expression simplifies nicely, and you get that the # of subgroupings scales as `(m^n)/m!`.

Comment: in your formula n!/(m!*k!)^m) why ^m is used? Sorry i am not good in math.

Comment: No problem. The ^m is because there are m different subgroups. Each one has k! different orderings of its elements, so you want to divide by k! once for each subgroup. So in your original example with n = 6 and k = 3, there are 6! total permutations of the elements, but we divide that by 3! because how the elements within the first subgroup are ordered doesn't matter, divide by 3! again for the second subgroup, and then divide by 2! since the order of the subgroups themselves doesn't matter. And that gives us 10.